# Is there any public API that allow me to get a list of jobs from Careers 2.0?

Tags: discussion, api, jobs

I looking for an API like the [Stack Overlow API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help), for jobs on Careers 2.0.
Is there any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you [can use RSS](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?) to get all the jobs:
[image: Jobs RSS location]

Comment: I noticed the RSS only gives the most recent 25 job postings on any given search criteria. Is there any way to go further back in the past than that?